# Differential of exponential map w.r.t. the point

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have a standard Riemmanian exponential map $\exp: TM \to M$ given by $\exp(s, v) = \gamma_s(1)$, where $s \in M, p \in T_s M$ and $\gamma$ is a geodesic with $\gamma(0) = s, \gamma'(0) = v$.

It is a standard fact that for $\exp_s$ ($\exp$ restricted to $T_s M$) we have $d_0\exp_s = id$.

I, however, want to know what is the differential of the full map $\exp$ when regarded as a map between manifolds $TM$ and $M$. In other words, I want to know how this map changes when we infinitesimally move point $s$ around. I believe that it should involve curvature tensor of the ambient manifold M; however, my attempts to calculate it were unsuccessful so far.

Because of that, my questions are:

1)How to approach this problem?

2)Is there a canonical choice of coordinates on $TM$ that would allow me to brute force it in coordinates? I was attempting to calculate it in Riemmann normal coordinates on $M$ together with the adapted frame on $T_s M$ moved to other points by parallel transport; in this case our mapping is nice on each fixed tangent space but is less nice on the zero section. Or maybe it is still ok - then I would appreciate an advice in this direction.

Thank you all!

Comment: You might consider the geodesic spray, the first-order ODE system on $TM$ which integrates to the geodesic flow. So now you'll be studying a fixed differential equation with varying initial conditions.

Comment: The differential of the exponential map is given by the value of a Jacobi field. Given $(p,v) \in TM$, let $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow M$ be the constant speed geodesic given by $\gamma(t) = \exp_p tv$, Given $(\dot{p}, \dot{v}) \in T(TM)$, $D_{(\dot{p},\dot{v})}(\exp_pv) = J(1)$, where $J$ is the Jacobi field, where $J(0) = \dot{p}$ and $J'(0) = \dot{v}$. The curvature appears, because the Jacobi field $J$ satisfies the Jacobi equation $J'' + KJ = 0$, where $K$ is part of the curvature tensor.

Comment: Opinion: I dislike working with the exponential map, including the standard notation used for representing it. I see a lot of confusion about how to work with it. The differential of the exponential map encodes information about the first variation of families of geodesics. In the end, it is always easier to do this using Jacobi fields and not mentioning the exponential map at all.

Comment: Just a precision: the differential of the exponential map at a point is not the identity. It is $\mathrm{d}\exp_p (0)$ that is equal to the identity of $T_pM$, but for other vector $v \in T_pM$, $\mathrm{d}\exp_p(v)$ isn't: as a linear map between two diferent vector spaces, it does not even have sense.

Comment: I believe i've seen (and did) a computation of this in Lee's Riemannian Manifold, 2nd ed. Unfortunately i can't write the details right now, so you might want to check it out directly on the book. It's on the proof of Lemma 6.14.

Comment: You might want to consider the diffential of the map $(x,v) \mapsto (x, exp_x v)$ locally on a neighbourhood first. And then the differential that you want is just the projection to the second factor of that differential above.

Comment: @Deane, thank you for that! This indeed does seem like a better approach: instead of looking at variation of the endpoint of geodesic, consider the whole geodesic and analyze its whole variation with the help of Jacobi fields. I will be moving in this direction indeed.

Comment: @Didier, sure, I meant it - will edit the question now. I just thought about adding this line to avoid confusion, as it seems to be the first thing that comes to mind with the words "differential of exponential map". Thanks anyway for the observation.

Comment: @SiKucing, thanks for the reference! I checked in there - Lee indeed mentions this differential but does not compute it. He uses it to show nondegeneracy of the mapping, and for it one does not need the explicit form - the fact that the differential of your mapping can be written in upper-triangular form suffices.